# Fire an event to animate main animation after one uiviewimage's animation completed(mono touch)

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, ios, xamarin.ios

Fire an event to animate main animation after one uiviewimage's animation completed.
ViewDidLoad()
 has the main animation logic. once it is loaded, there is an animation circle appears on the screen.

And there is a button on the screen it fires another animation for only 6 seconds.

I want a logic and method that makes possible to run the previous animation.

In my opinion It can be done with an call back or thread?

Please give your suggestion as an answer and a piece of code will be perfect if you suggest an call back method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Omar Johari's example, converted to MonoTouch:

```
UIView.Animate(0.6, 0d, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, 
               () => {
                      // Animations here
               }, 
               () => {
                      // After animation completes
               });
```

Comment: With threading I believe it's a bit rough around the edges, but glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     // Do your animations here.
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) {
                         // Do your method here after your animation.
                     }
                 }];
```

if u use Block u can allows call whatever u want after the animation finished.

Comment: [...]; this line goes to the block that is called when the button touched, yes?

Comment: You can call it whenever u want, what is your problem with that ??

Comment: @I need the version for mono touch

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this.

Make a function for your main screen animation

```
       -(void)mainScreenAnimation
       {
          // do ur code here
       }
```

Now when firing animation with a button add something like this to the button event

```
   -(IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender
   {
        // try implementing a timer which starts after 6seconds and the selector of the timer should be @selector(mainAnimationScreen)

         timer=  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(mainAnimationScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

     // if u want to repeat the animation then use this

       timer=  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(mainAnimationScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

   }
```